how to build a google cast device running linux
most of the documentation is about how to build a sender, but I want to build a cast hardware device with receiver software. There is almost no document on that, and google has no links for interested parties to even get started. Can third party build cast devices? if so how to start? to sign some license agreements or getting widewine DRM certificate/tokens somehow?
